# Having trouble looping through arrays

Tags: list-manipulation, infinite-loop

Apologies if this question is written in the incorrect format this is my first time posting here.

I am trying to generate a list of vectors whose x, y and z components can be made by selecting an element from an array of choices. Each component is made up of a product of the choices from the three arrays. Here is an example of the format of the choice arrays:

```
xchoice = [0, 1, Cos[α x], Sin[α x]] 
ychoice = [0, 1, Cos[β y], Sin[β y], Cos[2 β y], Sin[2 β y]] 
zchoice = [0, 1, Cos[γ z], Sin[γ z]]
```

And here are 2 examples of possible combinations of the choices creating vectors:

```
{Cos[2 y β] Sin[z γ], 0, 0}
```

or

```
{0, Sin[x α] Sin[2 y β] Sin[z γ], Cos[2 y β] Cos[z γ] Sin[x α]}
```

I would like to create a list of vectors corresponding to every different possible combination of the choices.I have tried using For loops but I cannot figure out a way that doesnt select the same choice for each component of the vector.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you seen `Tuples[]`?

Comment: This is not a well-posed question. Your examples do not show choosing one element from each of your element lists (which BTW are not expressed correctly as Mathematica lists}. You show multiple choices combined by Times without giving any constraints on how many factors can be chosen. You should be more clear.

Comment: Ah that helps a lot thank you! Just need to figure out how to obtain elements that are a product of choices from the lists

Comment: The idea is that for each vector component a multiplication of a choice from each of xchoice ychoice and zchoice must be made

Comment: If I now understand what you asking for, there are 97336 such vectors. Do you really want to generate such a  large list?

Answer (score 2):

Based on my current understanding of your question, here is how to proceed.

```
xchoice = {0, 1, Cos[α x], Sin[α x]};
ychoice = {0, 1, Cos[β y], Sin[β y], Cos[2 β y], Sin[2 β y]};
zchoice = {0, 1, Cos[γ z], Sin[γ z]};

vectors = 
  Tuples[DeleteDuplicates[Times @@@ Tuples[{xchoice, ychoice, zchoice}]], 3];

Length @ vectors
```

> `97336`

Here is a sample of the generated vectors.

```
SeedRandom[42]; RandomSample[vectors, 16] // Column
```

[image: vectors]

Comment: Thank you yes that is what I am looking for. The order of the problem will be reduced by requiring that the vectors have a divergence of zero. Is it possible to set it such that the x and z components have a different ychoice list to the y component?

Comment: @JamesHitchen. Your adding additional constraints in the above comment is exactly why I asked you to clarify your question in my comment on it. I suspected this was going to be a bait-and-switch question, which are not at all well-received here.

Comment: OK I was not aware of that. Thank you for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

You asked in comments for those vectors whose divergence is zero. You can use m_goldberg's code to generate those vectors, then calculate the divergence, then select those with zero divergence:

```
vectors = (* code from m_goldberg's answer *)

divs = Div[vectors, {x, y, z}];
Pick[vectors, Piecewise[{{True, # === 0}}, False] & /@ divs]
```

You could alternatively select vectors from the `vectors` list by calculating their divergence on the fly, e.g. using `Select[vectors, Div[#, {x, y, z}] == 0 &]`. However, this is much less efficient than using `Div` on a list directly, which allows the system to vectorize the operation and optimize it.